# Websocket availability using socketio

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to detect whether the websocket is running before allowing clients to connect to it. Consider the following code:

```
var socket = io.connect('1.1.1.1:1234');
        socket.on('connect',function() {
            console.log('Client has connected to the server');
        });

        socket.on('disconnect',function() {
            console.log("The client has disconnected from the server");
        });
```

How can I make sure that this block is only called if the server on that IP is actually running and how can I output a message to the users stating that the server is not up?

Thank you

Comment: You will need to establish connection to see if server is up or not. Event `connect` is designed exactly for this. Any action you take on client must be after `connect` event is emitted.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to fire the io.connect() atleast once (consider this as a ping) to detect if server is up, but you can then handle the failure to connect with the socket.on('connect_failed', function () {}) event handler and show a message to user that the 'server is down'. 
 Have a look at [Exposed Events](https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Exposed-events) for the client

Further, if you would want to reduce the number of times the reconnect is attempted, you can change the socket.io configuration setting for 'reconnect' to false.
 Checkout [Socket.io Configuration](https://github.com/LearnBoost/Socket.IO/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO) for more details